# Is there any way of selecting rows when using CSS to make columns?

Tags: css

I'm using CSS to turn an unordered list into columns, and I was wondering if there was any way I could then select the "rows"?

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
ul.popular{
    margin:15px 0 30px;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    -moz-columns:3;
    -webkit-columns:3;
    columns:3;
    -moz-column-gap:0;
    -webkit-column-gap:0;
    column-gap:0;
    list-style-position:inside;
    -moz-column-fill:balance;
    column-fill:balance;
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    break-inside:avoid;
    border-top:solid 1px #d2d3d4;
    border-left:solid 1px #d2d3d4
}
 ul.popular li{
    padding:10px 15px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #d2d3d4;
    border-right:solid 1px #d2d3d4;
    display:block
}
 ul.popular li a{
    display:block
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul class="popular">
    <li>Australia to Fiji</li>
    <li>Australia to Papua New Guinea</li>
    <li>Australia to Solomon Islands</li>
    <li>Australia to Tonga</li>
    <li>Australia to Vanuatu</li>
    <li>New Zealand to Fiji</li>
    <li>New Zealand to Papua New Guinea</li>
    <li>New Zealand to Solomon Islands</li>
    <li>New Zealand to Tonga</li>
    <li>New Zealand to Vanuatu</li>
    <li>United States of America to Fiji</li>
    <li>United States of America to Samoa</li>
    <li>United States of America to Tonga</li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cbkx1hLm/

I was wondering if there was any way I could make every second "row" a different background colour. So every second item of each column.

I've tried using nth-child(2n) and variables, also odd/even, with no luck.

Comment: Do you think that perhaps, maybe - it would be helpful if the question included an example of the HTML generated, rather than the code used to generate it? As it stands, I've no idea how much data I should create, and am frankly too lazy to be bothered to work out how I can go about working out how to solve a problem.

Comment: I've created a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cbkx1hLm/ I'm trying to give it a table look, without having to use a table. I was just hoping to also select every second item of each column to have the same background colour.

Comment: Basically no!  CSS-columns are not elements and so cannot be parsed/selected to determing what the 2nd item in each one is.

Comment: Thank you :) I changed the way I was outputting the information so I could use it in the way I needed to :)

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: **The question has been simplified, now refers to selecting "rows", and includes a working example.**

But when we look at the given example:

[image: Fiddle output]

There really aren't any obvious rows, and the "US to Fiji" item is split between two columns, so even if what you wanted *were* possible, the second part of that one item might require a different colour from the first part.

Even worse, what is there could change drastically depending upon the width of the window, font-size, etc.

It certainly seems like what your really want is a table.

Comment: I'm trying to do every second item of each column, not just every second item.